# count placement for insertionsort, correct?

Tags: java, sorting, counter, insertion-sort

I just want to double check that my counter for comparisons in an insertionsort method is correct. I think it is, but I just want to be sure. it's icount++; towards the bottom.

Thanks for reading.

```
public static void insertionsort(int[] arr)
  {
    int i, j, newValue;
    for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
      {
        newValue = arr[i];
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > newValue)
          {
            icount++;
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            j--;
          }
        arr[j] = newValue;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of comparisons between array elements, then it's almost right, but you're missing the case when the loop terminates when you find some position (not at the start) to insert the next element at.